# How to fix setValue:forUndefinedKey

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel

I am trying to create an app using Xcode, and I tried to create a label in one of the view controllers. When trying to run the app I am receiving this message in the app delegate"

```
Thread 1: Exception: "[<JournalApp.ViewController 0x7fe77e907e60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key CharacterCount."
```

"
(the label's outlet was called CharacterCount)
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the View Controller and remade it. The issue is fixed.